# Mac .Pkg File Opened In Windows...Strange Happenings

Tags: windows, macos, installation, explorer

I am a windows developer and I had to port an app to Mac.  I built it fine and have everything working except my installer.  I built my Package file (.pkg) which installs fine and works great on a Mac.

However, I want to move the file to a windows OS over a network to upload it to an ftp server.  My ftp client is on Windows.  I have done this before without issues on previous .pkg files but I just created one that is acting strange.  When I view most .pkg files in windows explorer, they are treated almost like an unknown file type.  Windows lets me see the file but I can't really do anything with it.  This is fine because I just want to move the file, not use it in any other way.

Unfortunately, I have a new .pkg file that windows strangely treats like a directory instead of just a single file.  I can open it and see the "Contents" folder and some internal files/binaries/whatever that I don't want to see.  While this is similar to the MacOS functionality, it causes problems because it is uploaded as a directory rather than a file.  I just want to drag it to my server and let people download it.  Why is this happening?

I have looked online a fair amount and nobody seems to have this issue.  It does seem to be permissions related.  I saw a good amount of people complaining about "Custom Access" and oddly enough, when I click "get info" on the file, it does say I have "custom access".  .Pkg files that seem to display correctly in windows explorer do not have this set.  Anyways I would really appreciate the help.  I could probably just get an ftp client on the Mac but this does seem really strange and it may help others if there is a solution.

Comment: If anyone has any ideas I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry that answer didn't helped, I thought your problem was that Windows shows your pkg as a directory (which it also is on Mac OS X) and that one can't download directories from FTP servers. Mind updating your question a bit to make it more clear what you actual problem is?

Comment: Hey JustSid, Sounds good.  I'll try and make it clearer.  It seems like there should be a simple fix but I haven't found it yet.  Thanks very much for the input.

Answer (score 4):

Historically, Mac OS X installer files have been built as bundles, or a directory that appears as a file in OS X. These types of installers will always appear as directories in Windows. However, Mac OS X 10.5 added support for a new format, which is simply the important parts of the installer compressed using [xar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xar_%28archiver%29). Since this format is an archive and not a bundle, it will show up as a single file in Windows.

PackageMaker can produce either format depending on the minimum target version you specified for the package. If you specify 10.5, it will create the new xar format, but if you specify an older version, it will create a bundled installer. If your application will only work for 10.5 and later, you can change the minimum version in PackageMaker by going to Project > Install Properties (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) and changing the Minimum Target dropdown. If you want to support older versions of OS X, then your only choice is to create the bundle version and either compress it as a zip file, or create a disk image to hold it.

Comment: ughoavgfhw, Thank you so much.  I don't know how mine was changed down to 10.4 but that makes perfect sense.  Thank you so much I really appreciate it.